# Can docker and cricontainerd co exist

Tags: docker, containers, command-line-interface, containerd

I have a node which has both `docker` and `cri-containerd` installed.
When I do `docker ps` nothing gets listed where as `crictl ps` lists some containers. Could any one explain in detail how these commands differ.
I have `ctr` installed as well. 
`ctr containers list` also doesn't list any containers.

Comment: Just an FYI , I cannot find nor am I able to create new tags for cri-containerd,crictl, ctr etc.

Comment: in the title you ask can the systems co-exist, but in the question body you ask for explanations on how these commands differ. Which is it?

Comment: @eis When there is difference in output of the commands which I have mentioned in the query [ considering the fact that all of those commands are intended to give same output as per my understanding.only the syntax is different], I have 1 ) doubt whether the system can co-exist , 2) if someone can answer the question above and little more details on the same would be helpful as the documentation for these clis are not sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [crictl doc](https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/crictl.md) carefully, the cri plugin uses the "k8s.io" containerd namespace.

You can list all containerd namespaces with `sudo ctr ns ls`:

```
$ sudo ctr ns ls
NAME   LABELS 
k8s.io        
moby
```

If you want to see containers created by crictl from ctr, be sure to add the `-n k8s.io` option

```
$ sudo ctr -n k8s.io containers ls
CONTAINER     IMAGE                              RUNTIME                  
ubuntu-crictl    docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest    io.containerd.runc.v2
```

Also, [here](https://youtu.be/FKoVztEQHss?t=1153) is a talk about various container runtimes on YouTube where the same problem is explained by the speaker.